# Sql query for getting group by on 2 columns

Tags: sql, pivot

I am expecting the result of having count of 2 different columns values

```
Name | fruits
----------------
Vishal | orange
Manish | orange
Vishal | apple
Manish | orange
Manish | apple
Vishal | orange
Vishal | mango
Vishal | banana
```

Result should be

```
Name | Orange count | Apple count| mango | banana
--------------------------
Vishal | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1
Manish | 2 | 1 | 0 | 0
```

Another result should be

```
name | fruits
---------------
Vishal | orange, Apple , mango, banana
Manish | orange , Apple
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What's the expected result if there's suddenly a pineapple in the table?

Comment: Yes ! Good one the fruit is basically a kind of category that is fixed . If a new category comes then I have to go and change the query and that is fine. Second part it depends at this time I do pre test on the ACcess database and in production it can be MS Sql or oracle 11g. But for sure it can't anything other than these 3 databases .

Comment: As already asked, which dbms product are you using? That last result can easily be done with some products, but is harder with others.

Comment: As mentioned "access database" and Microsoft sql server or oracle

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic pivot query which should work across most RDBMS:

```
SELECT Name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fruits = 'orange' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS orange_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fruits = 'apple'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS apple_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fruits = 'mango'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mango_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN fruits = 'banana' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS banana_count
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Name
```

If you are using SQL Server, Oracle, or Postgres, there are built-in `PIVOT` functions which can simplify this and possibly improve performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation for this:

```
select name, 
       count(case when fruits = 'orange' then 1 end) as orange_count, 
       count(case when fruits = 'apple' then 1 end) as apple_count, 
       count(case when fruits = 'mango' then 1 end) as mango_count, 
       count(case when fruits = 'banana' then 1 end) as banana_count
from the_table
group by name;
```

Some DBMS also support the ANSI SQL `filter` clause which makes this a bit more readable:

```
select name, 
       count(*) filter (where fruits = 'orange') as orange_count, 
       count(*) filter (where fruits = 'apple') as apple_count, 
       count(*) filter (where fruits = 'mango') as mango_count, 
       count(*) filter (where fruits = 'banana') as banana_count
from the_table
group by name;
```